Resonating string with increasing amplitude
The situation goes like this: We have a tuning fork at one end of a string (whose other end is fixed to a wall and length $L$). The fork is vibrating with small amplitude so we approximate this end of string as a fixed end.
The wave produced by fork after twice the reflection is to be in the same phase as the wave produced at that instant such that the twice reflected wave and the new wave show constructive interference with an amplitude of $2A$ and this process goes on for resonating length $L=n\lambda/2$.
What happens when the phase difference between the twice reflected wave and the produced wave is not a multiple of $2\pi$? Does it mean that $L$ is not equal to $n\lambda/2$? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The tuning fork is the driver and the string is the driven system.
When the standing wave is formed the system is in resonance but if that is not the case then you have forced oscillations with the string oscillating with a (much) smaller amplitude than that at resonance
